# Angular directive not picking up the values set by parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that has a div, whose visibility is set by its parent. Expecting "show" to be true, but the div is still not visible initially on page load.

```
Directive:
<div ng-show="{{ show }}">
        ...
</div>

angular.module('myModule').directive('myDiv', [
  function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: myController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrlr',
        templateUrl: 'myDiv.tpl.html'
    };
}]);

Parent:
<div myDiv show="ctrlr.shoudlShow()" ng-repeat="item in ctrlr.items">
</div>
```

There may be a possibility that shoudlShow() is returning false on page load, and later it turns true. Could it be that the directive myDiv is not picking up the latest values of shouldShow()? Do I need to watch for changes or anything?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-show` expects an expression not interpolation and you left out the `controllerAs` alias

Change to

```
<div ng-show="ctrlr.show">
```

A better approach would be to use a filter on `ng-repeat` instead or `ng-if`. Doesn't make sense adding all those elements (and the associated watches) if they aren't needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve, but When you create an Angular directive, The HTML attribute for a declared directive called **myDiv** should be **my-div** and not **myDiv** (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive))

```
Parent:
<div my-div show="ctrlr.shoudlShow()" ng-repeat="item in ctrlr.items">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a function called *shoudlShow()* and said function will return a boolean that will be passed to the directive. In this case you need to bind the variable that is returned to the directive, binding the function will not work. You could use something like

```
vm.isShown=vm.souldShow();
```

and then in your directive

```
<div myDiv show="ctrlr.isShown" ng-repeat="item in ctrlr.items">
</div>
```